# dropdown does work but not the way I want?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Now, it works but not the way I want. I want dropbox as the width of the dropdown. And only below it. Not the others.

Also, point me the mistakes that were made. I don't think my code is perfect. I learned from w3schools.com and I want to do it differently with them. Another approach.

```css
 .bar {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bar li > a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: lightskyblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.dd {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.bar li > a:hover {
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.dd_content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dd_content a  {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.dd_content a:hover {
  background: #aaa;
}

.dropdown:hover .dd_content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="bar">
    <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#News">News</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#Dropdown" class="dd">Dropdown</a>
      <div class="dd_content">
        <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out it worked for mine as you explained

just put the code snippet in given blew **dd_content** class

```
width: 33.33%;float: right;
```

Full code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="bar">
        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#News">News</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#Dropdown" class="dd">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dd_content">
                <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <style>
        .bar {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;

            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .bar li>a {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 33.33%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background: lightskyblue;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 15px;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
        }

        .dd {
            border-right: 1px solid black;
        }

        .bar li>a:hover {
            background: deepskyblue;
        }

        .dd_content {
            display: none;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 33.33%;
            float: right;
        }

        .dd_content a {
            clear: both;
            display: block;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
            padding: 10px 20px;
            min-width: 200px;
        }

        .dd_content a:hover {
            background: #aaa;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dd_content {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, your answer works. Thank you. But, what if my dorpdown is not at the right most side. What if it is in the middle somewhere. How can I do that?

Comment: if so, instead of float:right: you can use margin to adjust the position and give the width same as the dropdown button

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to specify the width of the dropdown `<li>`. It will resize the whole thing when the dropdown becomes visible. Its 8 characters so try `max-width: 8ch;` in your `.dropdown`.